# How to restore a PostgreSQL database from dat.gz files?

Tags: postgresql

I received some postgresql files from another party.

How can I restore the database?

I have

```
toc.dat
COMPLETE
3105.dat.gz
3107.dat.gz
3109.dat.gz
...
3126.dat.gz
```

There is a `3105.dat` file inside `3105.dat.gz`. There are not any SQL files.

Answer (score 7):

These files are created by `pg_dump`.

You can restore them with `pg_restore`. I assume you got a `.tar` file, containing these files.

Use: `pg_restore backup.tar`.

If you received these files as individual files, put them all in a directory and use:

`pg_restore -F directory you_directory`

A full documentation of `pg_restore` could be found in the official [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: It is not an exact explanation of the question. he said that There are not any SQL files.

Comment: `pg_restore dump.zip
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified`

Comment: About that error, as the docs says, now "f" param is lowercase, so it'll be:  `pg_restore -f directory you_directory` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: @manna, the documentation says that lowercase "f" is an option for the *output* file, not the *input* one.